# Message not defined discord.js chatbot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, chatbot

So I'm trying to get my bot to work but the code says message not defined. I have tried everything I know to do:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready!');
});

if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
}

if (command === "!hug") {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    message.channel.send("You have been hugged " + user);
}

client.login('my-bot-token');
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a event listener for a message, I think.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready!');
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }

    if (command === "!hug") {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first();
        message.channel.send("You have been hugged " + user);
    }
}

client.login('my-bot-token');
```